# MySQL Master Slave Asynchronous GTID Replication Failover over ProxySQL with little downtime

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, failover, master-slave-replication, proxysql

**This is a production setup and I have to perform a failover from Master A to new potential master B.**

**MySQL Version is 5.7 and CentOS 7 is the OS.**

I have a simple master slave setup with A as Master and B,C,D,E,F as async slaves. ProxySQL Cluster is also configured.
Master A (writer in ProxySQL) and Slaves B and C (readers in ProxySQL) are added to ProxySQL.

On all the slaves **`log_slave_updates`** is **`ON`** and **`log_bin`** is also **`ON`**.

On **`Master A`** **`read_only=0`** and **`Slaves B,C,D,E,F`** have **`read_only=1`**.

This is a **`GTID`** based replication with **`master_auto_position = 0`**.

**`A --> B,C,D,E,F this is the current replication topology`**

Now, I know for failover I have to choose either slave B or slave C because they are on proxy. I choose B as my new potential master. So, I have to move all the slaves from current Master A to new Master C. So the replication topology will be like this

**`B --> A,C,D,E,F -- proposed new topology`**

**My question is how do I move the slaves from Master A to new potential Master B?**
**How should I use the coordinates from new Master B? What procedure should I follow?**

Once I move the slaves I guess failover will be easy, I just tweak the **read_only** flag on old master and new master and proxy will take care of the connections.

I would really appreciate if a detailed procedure with explanation is provided.

I have gone through following links but couldn't understand the process
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960577/mysql-failover-how-to-choose-slave-as-new-master

https://serverfault.com/questions/303669/how-to-actually-use-mysql-slave-as-soon-the-master-is-failover-or-got-burnt

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html